# Code for Tweepy streamlistener gives error when coordinates or image no included in tweet

Tags: php, mysql, python-3.x, tweepy

I'm trying to push tweets to mysql db from my streamlistener. The code works when I include a tweet location in the tweet but fails when I don't.

How do I override this completely so it writes any tweet data available to the DB?

```
def on_data(self, data):

    all_data = json.loads(data)

    tweets              = (all_data["text"])
    tweet               = re.sub(r"http\S+", "", tweets) #removes URL from tweet text and outputs tweet
    created_at_time     = all_data["created_at"]
    created_at          = re.sub(r"\+\S+\s", "", created_at_time) #removes +0000 from tweet text and outputs created_at
    #image               = all_data["extended_entities"]["media"][0]["media_url_https"]
    #lng, lat            = all_data["coordinates"]["coordinates"]
    tweet_location      = (all_data["place"]["full_name"])

    c.execute("INSERT INTO location (tweet, created_at, tweet_location) VALUES (%s,%s,%s)",
        (tweet, created_at, tweet_location))

    conn.commit()

    print((tweet, created_at))

    return True

def on_error(self, status):
    print (status)
```

Whenever I tweet without a tweet_location i receive the following error:

Exception has occurred: TypeError
'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Comment: Are you passing in an uninitialised value for tweet_location in this case? It would be useful to see the table definition too - perhaps tweet_location is a key or declared as NOT NULL?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the issue by removing:

```
tweet_location      = (all_data["place"]["full_name"])
```

then adding the following keys to the list:

```
location            = (all_data["place"])           
tweet_location      = (all_data["place"])
```

then adding this if / else:

```
if location is not None:
    tweet_location = (all_data["place"]["full_name"])
else:
    pass
```